# Як правильніше "блог" чи "блоґ"?

Tags: вживання-слів, правопис

Крім Вікіпедії не знайшла інших джерел інформації, але навіть там в одному реченні: "Сукупність всіх бло**ґ**ів в Інтернеті прийнято називати бло**г**осферою."

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE!
Наші критерії якості вимагають, щоб запитання містило **контекст**.
Також, запитання, які не демонструють **спроби автора самостійно відповісти** на нього, змушують інших «вгадувати», чого саме хоче автор, і тому заважають надавати точні відповіді. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [ask] а також
[«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Щоб виправити запитання, натисніть [edit] у лівому нижньому куті під запитанням. Ще раз, ласкаво просимо і дякуємо, що приєдналися до спільноти!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75118/discussion-between-p-vovk-and-bytebuster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За чинним правописом — 2015

> #### [§ 87. G, H](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par87)
>
> **G** і **h** звичайно передаються літерою **г**: *авангард, агітація, агресор, гвардія, генетика, гімнастика, гоніометр, грандіозний, графік, грог, ембарго, лінгвістика, міграція; гандбол, гегемонія, гектар, гербарій, герцог, гінді* (мова), *гіпотеза, горизонт, госпіталь, гугенот, гумус; Гаага, Гавана, Гавр, Гарвард, Гаронна, Гвінея, Гельсінгфорс, Гельсінкі, Гіндустан, Гренландія, Греція, Йоганнесбург, Люксембург; Ганнібал, Гейне, Гете, Гізо, Гомер, Горацій, Горн, Гюго, Магомет.*

Тому: *бло**г***.

## Але є декілька *але*

1. Анґлійською звучить як [/blɔɡ, blɑɡ/](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/blog), цебто *блоґ*.
2. Чинний правопис багато залишив чого від совітованого правопису, коли *ґ* прибрали геть.

Цебто <del>теперішні</del> словники і правописи переважно ґрунтуються на поширеність серед люду, а не за чистотою мови. Тому в вільному вживанні все залежить від самих нас.

Цьому підтверджує і досовітний правопис

> [**Чуже h — g § 55.**](//r2u.org.ua/node/243) Чуже **h** передаємо нашим **г**, щождо чужого **g**, то в новіших запозиченнях його треба передавати через **ґ**, у запозиченнях же засвоєних давніше, особливо з грецької мови, віддаємо нашим **г** (порівн. § 54): *Англія, газ, газе́та, га́ма, гегемо́нія, гецеало́гія (ло́гіка...), генера́л, геній, геогра́фія (грама́тика, програ́ма, грамофо́н, діягра́ма, гра́фіка, грам, кілогра́м...), Герма́нія, гігіє́на, гімна́зія, гіпс, гра́дус, граф, Гру́зія, гру́па, дифто́нг, егої́зм, організа́ція, педаго́г, Ри́га, траге́дія, фігу́ра* й ін., але *аґе́нт, аґіта́ція, аґроном, Араґо́нія, бра́внінг, Брю́ґґе, Гамбурґ, Геґель, гіда́льґо, гуґено́ти, Гюґо́, ґарантія, Ґаро́нна, ґва́рдія, Ґвіне́я, Ґе́ргард, Ґе́те, Ґеттінґен, ґібелі́н, ґірля́нда, ґля́вберова сіль, ґлядія́тор, ґнайс, Ґо́льфштром, Ґрана́да, ґрандіо́зний, Ґріґ, ґу́ма, Ґустав, дириґе́нт, елеґа́нтний, інтеліґе́нт, лінґві́ст, міґра́ція, Чіка́ґо* і т. ін.

Також вельми цікава і дивна [примітка до § 15](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par15prym) про **букву ґ** в чинному правописі:

> У власних назвах іншомовного походження етимологічний **g** згідно з усталеною традицією вимовляється як **г**; проте збереження **g** у вимові не є порушенням орфоепічної норми. Отже, правильною є вимова: *Гданськ* і *Ґданськ*, *Гренландія* й *Ґренландія*, *Гібралтар* і *Ґібралтар*; *Гарібальді* й *Ґарібальді*, *Гете* й *Ґете*.

Comment: Тут би, по-моєму, пасувала інформація про те, що чинний «Правопис» ([примітка до § 15](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par15prym)) дозволяє **вимовляти** у **власних** назвах іншомовного походження /ґ/ (коли в оригіналі звучить /g/) — але, на жаль, не сказано чітко: лише вимовляти, чи й писати теж — і в будь-якому разі це наразі стосується лише власних назв.

Comment: Але ще є правила транслітерації від кабміну, НУ

Answer (score 0):

Згідно із Словником української мови online (1-8 томи) правильно

> [**"блог"**](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=191052&page=180) у, ч., інформ. Веб-сайт, головний зміст якого – записи, зображення та
>   мультимедіа злободенної тематики, що регулярно додаються.

В **[Словнику Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/577-baga.html#show_point)** слово **"блоґ"** відсутнє.

З усіма словами в яких використовується буква "ґ" можна ознайомитися в даному **[Переліку слів з буквою Ґ за словником Бориса Грінчека](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2_%D0%B7_%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8E_%D2%90_%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%93%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0)**

Comment: @Follower я з Вами згодна. Будь ласка, додайте Вашу відповідь. Єдине джерело, яке я знайшла з словом "блоґ" стаття в Вікіпедії https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3