# Як правильно перекласти Ian Goodfellow

Tags: переклад, власні-назви

Підкажіть як перекласти *Ian Goodfellow*. Тут для мене три проблеми, всі у прізвищі:

1. *G* -> *Г* чи *Ґ*
2. *ll* -> *лл* чи *л*
3. *w* -> *у* чи *в*

Цікаву статтю на тему знайшов на архівній сторінці українського BBC - [Ноу хау чи нов гав? Г чи х?](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/forum/story/2006/04/060426_h_chy_kh_debate_kk.shtml), але довга дискусія не дала відповіді. Наведу лише перший коментар, який мені сподобався своїю чіткістю і зрозу, але наскільки він правильний?

> В англійській мові літерою H позначається звук, що найближчий до
>   українського Г (ге) (за винятком випадків, коли літера H не
>   вимовляється). І так і має транслітеруватися, як у власних так і в
>   загальних назвах іноземного походження: *Гайд-Парк, Гаїті, Галіфакс,
>   Гамбурґ, Гемпшир, Гавана, Копенгаґен, Гітлер; гідродинаміка, гіпотеза,
>   гіпербола, гомо сапієнс, горизонт, готель, гуманізм.* Очевидно, що така
>   транслітерація здебільшого і вживалася за радянських часів. Це
>   по-перше. По-друге, літера В (ве) в українській мові в кінці складу
>   позначає звук - нескладове У, що є найближчим українським
>   відповідником до англійського W (звука, що позначається літерою W).
>   Те, що при транслітеруванні може виникнути випадковий збіг з іншим
>   українським словом, не є підставою вигадувати інші правила. Отже, ім'я
>   чи прізвище Howe повинно перекладатися як *Гав*, *Harms* - як *Гармс, Henry
>   - Генрі, Herbert - Герберт, Herman - Герман* (а не так, як тут дехто з дописувачів пропонує). А словосполучення "! *know how*" має писатися і
>   читатися(!) "*нов гав*" (як уже було сказано літера В тут позначає
>   нескладове У). Так само не бачу проблем ні з "th", ні з "ph". Th має
>   транслітеруватися як Т (*Темза, Тибет; математика, теорія, термометр*) ,
>   а Ph - як Ф (*Філадельфія, Філіппіни; фізика, філологія, телефон*).
>   Винятки, взагалі кажучи, можливі у давно запозичених словах.
>
> *Роман Писак, США.*

Comment: Я б записав як Ієн Добрийтовариш. Ієн - бо так чую, коли вимовляє Ґуґл перекладач, а прізвище - бо так перекладається. Але на відповідь це не тягне, мабуть.

Comment: Якшчо за [Американською](http://upodn.com/phon.php) вимовою, то буде [iən gʊdfɛlo]. Звук [ə] десь поміж двома __е__ і ненаголошеної __а__. Сполука _і + голосна_ зазвичай ся йотують, тому просто _Єн_ або за мойому _Ян_. Людина [справжня](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_Goodfellow), тому переклад дешчо сумнівний, таке можна, гадаю, хиба́ до земльописних назв.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Було

- [Глітер чи ґлітер?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5089/585)
- [Правила вживання літери г/ґ/х при запозиченні іншомовних слів на g/h (гакер, гостинг)](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/347/585)
- [Як правильніше "блог" чи "блоґ"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3620/585)
- [Переклад слова "Rickrolling"](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3834/585)

Видно, вже обговорювали про [ɡ], і, певен, же десь навіть було про подвоєнь і *w*. Тоді чому відповідаю? Просто вони всї до 2019 року, тому, на мою думку, буде слушно відповісти, а потім уточнити ті старі, якшчо зміни були.

### Правопис 2019

> <sub>**[§ 122. Звуки [g], [h]](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=125)**</sub>
>
> 3. У прізвищах та іменах людей допускається передавання звука [ɡ]
>      двома способами: шляхом адаптації до звукового ладу української мови —
>      буквою **г** (*Вергі́лій, Гарсі́я, Ге́гель, Гео́рг, Ге́те, Грегуа́р, Гулліве́р*) і шляхом
>      імітації іншомовного [ɡ] — буквою **ґ** (*Верґі́лій, Ґарсі́я, Ге́ґель, Ґео́рґ, 
>      Ґе́те, Ґреґуа́р, Ґулліве́р* і т. ін.).
>
> ---
>
> <sub>**§ 124. Букви *w*, *th* у словах англійського походження**</sub>
>
> Англійське **w** на позначення звука [w] передаємо звичайно через **в**:
>   *віке́нд, Вашингто́н, Ве́бстер, Веллінгто́н, Ві́льсон, Вінніпе́г* та ін.; у деяких
>   словах за традицією через **у**: *Уе́льс, уайт-спірит* та ін.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>**[§ 128. Неподвоєні й подвоєні букви на позначення приголосних](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=126)**</sub>
>
> 3. Подвоєння букв на позначення приголосних переважно зберігаємо у
>      власних назвах: *Андо́рра, Бессеме́р, Білл, Боттіче́ллі, Гаро́нна, Голла́ндія,
>      Ллойд, Маро́кко, Міссу́рі, Ні́цца, Я́ффа; Бе́тті, Джо́нні, Мю́ллер, Руссо́,
>      Те́ннессі, Смо́ллетт, Кі́ркконнелл* […].
>
>    **Примітка.** За усталеною традицією в деяких власних назвах подвоєння не
>      зберігаємо (*Пенсільва́нія*) або зберігаємо частково (*Міссісі́пі*).

### Тлум і висновок

- [h] → **г** чи **ґ**
- [w] → **в**
- *ll* → **лл**

Тому: **Ґудфеллов** чи **Гудфеллов**. Хоча тут є питанє з **w**, але то вже далї.

### Мої думки і розбори

Роздїл правопису для иномовних слів мусе мати складову:

- Розбір абетки [МФА](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82) — як записувати звуки Украйинською абеткою і обмеги Украйинського звуцтва. Наприклад мʼякі губні і низка приголосних не є мʼякими питомо, а отже такого бажано уникати.
- Вказати, же важлива рівновага між звуцтвом і словотвором. Наприклад певні частини слова завше матимуть такого набору звуків незалежно від йихього розташову.
- І нарешті винятки до кожної мови, мов чи родини мов, якшчо є така можливість. А також короткі особливостї про мов.

Так, роздїл виросте, але так природно за часи ґлобализму. Варто взагалі згадати, же раніше в правописах навіть такого роздїлу не було або був дуже малим. Наприклад, правопис Желехівського бува навіть радив записувати малознаних імй латиницьою як є, а там поглянемо:

> Меньше знані чужі імена власні найлїпше писати так, як они пишуть ся в чужих мовах. До таких імен власних належать н. пр. *Branchelli, Mascagni, Du Bois-Raymond, Fizeau, Foucault, Fresnel, Mirabaud, Mirabeau, Salesbury, ten Brink, van Houten, O’Connell, Lützow, Wörishofen*…

Отже, таким чином шчонайменше:

- Не буде дивного подїлу на загальні і власні слова.
- Непотрібні подвоєня будуть прибрані.
- Гинші дивини будуть прибрані, наприклад: Польське правило девʼятки.
- Моя уява, але можливо в майбутньому переглянуть декотру складову Украйинської мови і абетки, наприклад зведуть абетку до виду драгоманівки.

Я свойого часу розробʼяв [МФА Анґлської](https://write.as/isd/narys-holosnyx-mfa) до мови. Так, там можливі вади (я от вже декілька разів виправʼяв після зауваг), до того ж взяті звуки від *[прийнятої Анґлської вимови](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)*, хоча самих вимов [достобіса](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects), але основа вже є.

З незвичного для багатьох буде запис [ð] як **ѕ** (*дз*), а [θ] — **ц**.

Якшчо розглядати вашого питаня, то тут я наприклад дав кожної букви з відомої трійки до застосову:

- **г** для [h];
- **ґ** для [ɡ];
- **х** для [x], етимолоґичного запису чи для говірок.

А **в** для [w]. Але тут треба бути обачним, бо сама **w** (не звук) може також позначати і [ʊ], шчо є навіть для ПВ *fellow*, коли для Американської вимови взагалі буде просто *фело*. Також можливі проблеми з розріжнєм слів як *wine* і *vine*. І така проблема не лише на початку корня: *love* – *low*.

Тому в мойому випадку радше буде **Ян Ґудфелоу**, допоки не вигадав вирїшенє питаня.